# splash screen customisation on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, plymouth

I have customised splash screen logo which i'm able to see after rebooting the system. But on boot-up screen still i'm getting ubuntu logo. Any idea how to get customised splash screen logo on Boot-up.

Please share your views. Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go under the Image menu and choose scale. Key in the required numbers, keep the ratio intact. If you don’t get the exact numbers, go for slightly larger values but keep the ratio intact. I suggest you back up all the images in `/usr/share/images/xsplash` into another folder on your hard drive just in case things go wrong. Then put the required file(s) into `/usr/share/images/xsplash`.

Comment: I don't have graphical user mode. I'm running lightdm on my embedded system. How to change ratio using command line?